# I'm trying to pull all the text past one point in a file and print it on the screen using bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

This is my input and output:

```
cat /home/$USER/Downloads/cudaHashcat-1.37/cudaHashcat.pot | grep :
$6$Tgjtsn2v$dT2el6ZxY9ADYl2WlZE6UdCkDyczwztDoXvtym6KEZv6vkZjNHDbTv.vTVHeQSIrt61uWpbD/gisf3bcET8VK.:Butterfly123
```

I'm trying to pull everything past the colon in the user hash and print it on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out using sed:

```
$ sed 's/^.*://' /home/$USER/Downloads/cudaHashcat-1.37/cudaHashcat.pot 
Butterfly123
```

The `sed` command will replace everything until the first `:` with nothing, effectively removing it.

Comment: [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat): `sed` takes a file name as it's argument...

Comment: FYI: Judging by the fact you `grep`ed for `:` in the file, I'm assuming there could be other lines in the file that don't contain a `:`. If that's the case, to make `sed` only work on (and display) the lines that contain a `:`, you can do `sed -n '/:/ s/.*://p filename`. We use `/:/` before our `s///` to tell it to only do this on lines that match `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
awk -F':' '{print $2}' /home/$USER/Downloads/cudaHashcat-1.37/cudaHashcat.pot
```

The `-F:` sets the field delimiter to `:` and then the `awk` script prints the second field.